# Using JavaMail reading from gmail issue

Tags: macos, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am having problems reading mails from gmail (pop3) using javamail. I have a code that woks perfectly if the mail was sent from ubuntu's Thnderbird. How ever if the mail was originally sent from mac it fails.

This is the code I ham using:

```
    private static final String UNKNOWN_BRAND_PATH = "UNKNOWN";
public static final String FOLDER_NAME = "INBOX";

private static Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LzMailRecieverService.class);

@Value("${lz.mail.address}")
private String lzMailUserName;

@Value("${lz.mail.password}")
private String lzMailPassword;

@Value("${lz.mail.tmp.folder}")
private String lzMailTmpFolder;

public Store connect() throws Exception {

    String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

    Properties pop3Props = new Properties();

    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", "995");
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");

    URLName url = new URLName("pop3", "pop.gmail.com", 995, "", lzMailUserName, lzMailPassword);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props, null);
    Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);
    store.connect();
    return store;
}

public Folder openFolder(Store store) throws MessagingException {
    Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
    folder = folder.getFolder(FOLDER_NAME);
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    return folder;
}

public List<MailDetails> readAttachement(Folder folder) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
    List<MailDetails> mailDetails = new ArrayList<MailDetails>();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        logMailDetails(message);
        if (message.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())) {

                    continue; // dealing with attachments only
                }
                InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                String uid = getUid(message);
                String to = getTo(message);
                String from = getFrom(message);
                File d = new File(lzMailTmpFolder + File.separator + uid);
                if (d.exists() == false) {
                    d.mkdir();
                }
                File f = new File(d, new DateTime().getMillis() + "-" + bodyPart.getFileName());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
                MailDetails md = new MailDetails(to, from, f, uid);
                mailDetails.add(md);
            }
        }
        else {
            LOG.warn("Message conteant is not Multipart " + message.getContentType() + " skipping ...");
        }
    }
    return mailDetails;
}

private String getFrom(Message message) throws MessagingException {
    Address[] froms = message.getFrom();
    return froms[0].toString();
}

private String getTo(Message message) throws MessagingException {
    Address[] tos = message.getAllRecipients();
    return tos[0].toString();
}

public void logMailDetails(Message m) throws MessagingException {
    Address[] f = m.getFrom();
    if (f != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < f.length; j++)
            LOG.debug("FROM: " + f[j].toString());
    }

    Address[] r = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
    if (r != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
            LOG.debug("TO: " + r[j].toString());
        }
    }
    LOG.debug("SUBJECT: " + m.getSubject());
    Date d = m.getSentDate();
    LOG.debug("SendDate: " + d);
}

private String getUid(Message m) throws MessagingException {
    try {
        Address[] tos = m.getAllRecipients();
        String to = tos[0].toString();
        to = to.split("@")[0];
        String[] parts = to.split("\\+");
        return parts[parts.length - 1];
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Failes to extract brand hash from email address " + Lists.newArrayList(m.getFrom()));
        return UNKNOWN_BRAND_PATH;
    }
}
```

The problem is that for the mails originally created in mac bodyPart.getDisposition() always returns null. No matter what I have tried I could not understand which part is the attachment part (this is what I really need: extracting the attachment from the mail).

I have looked all over the web to find ewhat is the reason for that and I failed to find an answer. How ever I found the below note written by Juergen Hoeller that indicates that there might be an issue here (more details here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html)

Warning regarding multipart mails: Simple MIME messages that just contain HTML text but     no inline elements or attachments will work on more or less any email client that is capable of HTML rendering. However, inline elements and attachments are still a major compatibility issue between email clients: It's virtually impossible to get inline elements and attachments working across Microsoft Outlook, Lotus Notes and Mac Mail. Consider choosing a specific multipart mode for your needs: The javadoc on the 
MULTIPART_MODE   constants contains more detailed information.

Is there any example or explnation regarding using JavaMail if the mails are sent from Mac??

Yosi

Answer (score 0):

The "disposition" is at best a hint; it's not required to be included.

These JavaMail FAQ entries might help:

- [How do I tell if a message has attachments?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#hasattach)
- [How do I find the main message body in a message that has attachments?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody)
- [What are some of the most common mistakes people make when using JavaMail?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)